# Export Registry Tree to XML

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, registry

I would like to export a registry key and its child keys to an XML friendly format, not .REG. This will be for reporting purposes only not for importing later on.

When doing the following code, it gives me the data I want, just not XML compatible. Any suggestions on how to create a batch file/vbs that will do what I need?

```
REG QUERY hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall /s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out on my own. I used for loops to enumerate each Registry key, and then used the echo command to output the information into a CSV file and an XML document. Here is an example for those who may want to try to do the same. (not my exact code)

```
Echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?^> >>myxml.xml
Echo ^<document^> >>myxml.xml
Echo ^<Computer Name="%Computername%"^> >>myxml.xml
Echo ^<Applications^> >>myxml.xml

for /f "tokens=7 delims=\" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall ^|findstr /v "KB1 KB2 KB3 KB4 KB5 KB6 KB7 KB8 KB9"') do ( 

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%%a" |Findstr /i ".displayVersion">version.txt
for /f "tokens=3*" %%c in (version.txt) do echo %%c %%d>version1.txt
if EXIST version1.txt set /p version=<version1.txt

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%%a" |Findstr /i ".displayName">Name.txt
for /f "tokens=3*" %%e in (Name.txt) do echo %%e %%f>Name1.txt
if EXIST name1.txt Set /p name=<name1.txt

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%%a" |Findstr /i ".InstallDate">InstallDate.txt
for /f "tokens=3*" %%j in (Installdate.txt) do echo %%j %%k>InstallDate1.txt
IF EXIST Installdate1.txt set /p installdate=<Installdate1.txt


reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%%a" |Findstr /i ".UninstallString">UString.txt
for /f "tokens=3*" %%l in (Ustring.txt) do echo %%l %%m>Ustring2.txt
if exist Ustring2.txt type Ustring2.txt|findstr /v "&">Ustring1.txt
IF EXIST  Ustring1.txt set /p Ustring=<Ustring1.txt

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%%a" |Findstr /i ".Publisher">Publisher.txt
for /f "tokens=3*" %%n in (Publisher.txt) do echo %%n %%o>Publisher1.txt
IF EXIST Publisher1.txt set /p Publisher=<Publisher1.txt

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%%a" |Findstr /i ".InstallLocation">Installloc.txt
for /f "tokens=3*" %%v in (Installloc.txt) do echo %%v %%w>Installloc1.txt
IF EXIST Installloc1.txt set /p Installloc=<Installloc1.txt


if NOT defined installdate set installdate=N/A
if NOT defined name set name=%%a
if NOT defined version set version=N/A
if NOT defined Ustring set Ustring=N/A
if NOT defined Publisher set Publisher=N/A
if NOT defined Installloc set Installloc=N/A
echo !name:^&=!'!version!'!Publisher:^&=!'!Installdate!'!Installloc:^&=!'!UString! >>programlist.csv
)

::Now Creating XML from CSV

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims='" %%p in (programlist.csv) DO (

echo ^<Product Name="%%p"^> >>myxml.xml
echo        ^<Version^>%%q^</Version^> >>myxml.xml
echo        ^<Publisher^>%%r^</Publisher^> >>myxml.xml
echo        ^<Installdate^>%%s^</Installdate^> >>myxml.xml
echo        ^<installLocation^>%%t^</installLocation^> >>myxml.xml
echo        ^<UninstallString^>%%u^</UninstallString^> >>myxml.xml

echo ^</Product^> >>myxml.xml
)

Echo ^</Applications^>  >>myxml.xml
echo ^</Computer^> >>myxml.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

A plan:

1. Start to write a schema file (xsd) to make you think about nodes/elements, attributes, and data types
2. Use a recursive directory walker to design a recursive registry walker (probably using WMI); look at the methods Scriptomatic2 uses to export WMI info to XML
3. (Re)Read the XML documentation with emphasis on Create/Clone functions to come up with a strategy to put registry info into the XML tree

(If you publish a decent plan, I'm willing to help you with the implementation.)